# Workstation-like environment across Debian clients

Tags: networking, users, login, file-sharing, application

At our university we have a workstation-like system.
It's windows XP (or Win-7 on some machines) and you can sit to any computer and log in with your credentials.
It seems to be pulling some of your personal data via network: desktop-icons, documents you store, etc.
All I know is this: there's a server and your data is stored there.

My questions are:

1st: How do they call such systems?

```
I can not even start exploring my options without knowing the name.
```

2nd: Can I create something similar across Debians (Xubuntu, Ubuntu clients)?

```
I'd like to share application data across clients:
-Downloads
-Documents
-Browser history
```

I have the idea of mounting /home/ from a network drive, and when you log on ie. /home/adam/ will point to the server's folder of my personal data.

Is this feasible at all? Or what's the convenient way to solve this?

Comment: I believe with Windows it's called a profile. On linux mounting the user's home directory remotely would offer the same functionality. Search for autofs / automount / nis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe that your expectations can be viewed as two things .

the first is to let many machines check their users against one central server , so we don't have to create a duplicate account and a credential on each client machine before logging in if we have already have this on the central server . a term describing such systems is *single-sign-on* . though a wikipedia artical of this title covers broader matters including openid and other web based services . ( i keep seeing sayings that authentication and authorisation are two different issues but personally don't quite understand . )

the second is to access many networked data as if the data are on the local machine , but are synchorised when we are walking from one client machine to another . we may call this behavior *"roaming home directory"* or *"roaming profile"* .

so for the single-sign-on problem windows deploys *[domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/windows_domain)* . there are implementations on unix systems to interoperate with windows domains . one implementation is samba . with samba installed a unix system can join a windows domain or set up and become controller of a windows domain . there are other single-sign-on solution for unix . i am not familiar with those technologies , but i believe [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/309887/192294) have good explanations , and also discusses about roaming home directories .

for roaming directories , the windows roaming profiles solution is in detail described in [this article from samba](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Windows_Profiles) , the article also have instructions configuring unix machines to visit or host windows roaming profiles . there is an abundance of other unix solutions for roaming directories . basically we can just adopt any networked filesystem like the nfs , the windows cifs , the 9p of plan9 , or the amazon s3 , then write some small automation to make a *mount(2)(8)* happen on login . maybe some locking is favourable for avoiding writes on a same file from multiple places . we may further come up with some local cache .

---

in my own experience i have a small handful of machines and don't usually access them across an internet so i just make a same account name and passphrase locally on each machine . and i use *sshfs(1)* to push and pull directories and files across machines .

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and the time you spent on it). It's really useful as it's not mentioning any concrete solutions; only terms and articles which I can read where to start. Exactly the kind of answer I was expecting.